# Is there an extension or setting to quickly change the default search engine for chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extensions, search-engines

I've found that I now use the ombibar for searching anything and everything. I've got a plugin for rally for work, a plugin for steam for play, 'kipedia for research, and a handful of plugins for SE sites.

I find that if I'm searching on say, Rally, I will tend to be searching on Rally for a few hours consecutively. The same can be said of steam, or google, or wikipedia, and to a lesser extent the SE sites. This being the case, it's a pain to have to specify which search engine I want to use every time I use the omnibar, it would be much nicer if I could change the current default search engine to match the website I'm currently browsing without going through the sixteen or so clicks to set it in the browser options menu.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you right click on the omnibox you can *“Edit search engines”*.

You will see a box with three columns:

- The leftmost is the search engine.
- the rightmost the URL of the search engine
- The middle column  a **shortcut** that you can assign to the *search engine*.

  You can have a shortcut for *yahoo* (**y**, for example), other for *amazon* (**am**, for example) and other for *wikipedia* (**w**, for example).

So, if you need to search on wikipedia about *earth*, for example, you will issue:

```
w earth
```

And you'll get the result from *Wikipedia* instead from the default search engine

Answer (score 0):

Go into Chrome settings,
search for search 
to find "Manage Search Engines".

There you will probably find many already defined (I appear to have a couple hundred), as well as a link to official Chrome documentation.

You need to scroll down to the bottom to see what the columns mean:  they are name, keyword, and search URL.  If you click in the middle column for wikipedia and change it to be just 'wk', when you type 'wk' in the omnibox you will see the search change from google to "Search Wikipedia:" (try it).

I don't know about Rally or Steam, but I see I already have stackoverflow defined (use Ctrl-f/Cmd-f to search).  For convenience, I can click in the second column and change it to "so"; then, when I type "so fizzbuzz" in the omnibox and hit enter, The `%s` parameter in `http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%s` gets replaced properly with `fizzbuzz` taking me very conveniently to my search.

You can enter whatever search engine(s) you like, with any abbreviation, or change the default search engine from the setting page.  Changing the default does not disable using the 'keyword' selection of other search engines, but making it more convenient by being only a keystroke or two away, you might not ever need or want to change it.

Answer (score 0):

jcbermu's answer was half of what I was looking for for this (I didn't realise that you could right click the omnibar itself). The other half was that you can simply click "make default" in the window that opens upon that action (although the shortcuts are handy for one off searches)

[image]